# Block funtion back in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm a newbie so I don't know how to block function back when I use navigator 
Ex: You have a Login Page so after signed-in and I can't back Login Page

```
// This is code of Page 1

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterapp/Page2.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: Page1(),
));

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Page 1"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed:() {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2()));
            },
          child: Text("Page 2"),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}
```

// This is code of Page 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Page 2"),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of "**push**"

don't use

```
Navigator.of(context).push
```

use 
[pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)
or
[pushReplacement](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html)